# Referencing custom environment

Tags: tables, macros, environments

I am using

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:fig_name}
\end{figure}
```

and

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}
....
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:table_name}
\end{figure}
```

but I also need a custom environment `iteration` having layout:

```
Hypothesis:
<text>

Validation:
<text>
```

and I need to be able to reference it with `\ref{it:iteration_name}`.

How is this possible? I have seen the command `\newenvironment` but it doesn't seem to fit my needs. I could maybe just use the `figure` or `table` environment but the counter should be independent from the tables and figures when I'm referencing them.

## Edit

I want the new environment with content

```
Hypothesis:
<text>

Validation:
<text>
```

to be numbered. It should work just like figures/tables, so the entire environment is numbered but neither the text "Hypothesis" nor "Validation". I also want to color the background so it's more clear that the environment "stands out" as "independent" from the rest of the document.

Comment: You might want to give some more information. Is Hypothesis numbered? You need something for `\label` to latch on to.

Comment: Maybe a theorem-like environment is all you need?

Comment: Just like figure and table? So it shall float around the document? Or always stay where you are putting it?

Comment: It should actually always stay where I'm putting it, so not quite the same as figures and tables :-D But I'm already using the package `float` to make them stay where I placed them. It seems that theorem-like environment could almost do what I need. I have seen that I can use theorem and proof together but I'm afraid I'll also need a conclusion. So instead of only Hypothesis and Validation, I'll also need conclusion. Besides, can I set a background color to theorem and proof so it's more clear that they belong together?

Comment: @Jamgreen: `tcolorbox` is what you want, for example

Comment: Please tell us how the `iteration` environment is defined. In essence, we need to find out where a counter associated with the environment is defined and how it is incremented.

Comment: @Mico: I believe the `iteration` is not yet defined by the OP. I understand the question as a *feature-request*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A suggestion, to keep track of options and arguments, is to replace the `iteration` environment by a command, having some optional arguments etc.

The typesetting will be done within of a `tcolorbox` box environment. The counter is incremented automatically and reset with each section.

Please note, that the label must be used in the first optional argument as `label=it:somelabelname`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{ulem}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{iteration}[section]

\newtcolorbox[use counter=iteration]{iterationbox}[1][]{arc=0pt, auto outer arc,left=2pt,right=2pt,colback=LightBlue,colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=black,title={Iteration \thetcbcounter},#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\iteration}{+O{}+m+m+o}{%
  \begin{iterationbox}[#1]
    \uline{Hypothesis}:

    #2

    \uline{Validation}:

    #3

   \IfValueT{#4}{%

     \uline{Validation}:

     #4
   }%
 \end{iterationbox}
}



\begin{document}

In \ref{it:brontosaurs}, we will see that...


\iteration[label=it:brontosaurs,colbacktitle=red,colback=yellow]{Theory on Brontosaurs}{Excavate a brontosaur}  


\iteration[label={it:brontosaurs_extended},colbacktitle=red,colback=yellow]{Extended theory on Brontosaurs}{Excavate a brontosaur

\blindtext}[There must have been Brontosaurs]  


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you just come back from a vacation in Spain? :-)

Comment: @Mico: Nope, "Badische Landesfarben" :D

Comment: @cfr: I prefer `hideous` over `hilarious` :-P  ... I would not use those colours for my own documents :D